# ¿bloquear la pantalla cuando se envía archivos?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dropzone.js

Estoy usando BlockUi  de jQuery, y Dropzone este ultimo me sirve para subir archivos .config:

```
dropzone = new Dropzone(
    "#dropzone-archivo",
    {
        url : context + "/upload/archivo",
        autoProcessQueue : false,
        maxFiles : maxfiles == null ? 1 : maxfiles,
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        sending : function(file, xhr, formData) {
            formData.append("id", modelo[CAMPO_ID]);
            formData.append("TIPO_OBJETO", TIPO_OBJETO);
        },
        init : function() {
            self = this;
            self.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                alert("se agrego el archivo " + file.name);
            });
            self.on("processing", function() {
                console.log("se esta procesando")
                $.blockUI();
            })
            self.on("queuecomplete", function() {
                console.log("se esta procesando")
                $.unblockUI();
            })
            self.on("success", function(file) {
                self.removeFile(file);
                CRUD.filtrarLista();
                jqGrid.jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");
            })
        },
        maxfilesexceeded : function(file) {
            alert("solo es permitido" + self.options.maxFiles
                    + " archivos");
            dropzone.removeFile(file);
        },
        dictDefaultMessage : "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload'></i> click para subir archivo ",
        dictResponseError : "ERROR al subir: Codigo {{statusCode}}.",
        dictCancelUpload : "Cancelar subida.",
        dictCancelUploadConfirmation : "Seguro que quiere cancelar la subida?",
        dictRemoveFile : "Quitar archivo.",
        dictMaxFilesExceeded : "Ud. no puede subir más archivos.",
    });
```

Mi método Ajax, para guardar el objeto del formulario es este:

```
CRUD.prototype.guardarObjeto = function(args) {
var array = $("#objeto-form").serializeArray();
form = $("#objeto-form").validate({
    ignore : []
});
$.validator.addClassRules({
    number : {
        number : true
    },
    digito : {
        digits : true
    }
});
    form.form(); // valida formulario
    if (form.valid()) {
        var data = modelo;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].value != '') {
                data[array[i].name] = array[i].value;
            }
        }
        $.ajax({
            url : URL_CONTROLADOR + "guardar",
            type : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success : function(r) {
                modelo[CAMPO_ID] = r.id;
                alert("Guardado Correcto!");
                console.log(modelo)
                var flag = 1;
                if (args) {
                    console.log(args)
                    if (args.closemodal == false) {
                        flag = 0;
                        console.log("entro al if")
                        verificacionContrato()
                    }
                }
                if (flag != 0) {
                    hideModal();
                }
                if (dropzone) { 
                    self.processQueue(); // ACA RECIÉN PROCESA EL ARCHIVO
                    if (!dropzone.files.length)
                        jqGrid.jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");
                } else {
                    jqGrid.jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid");
                }
            },
            error : function(r) {
                alert("hubo un error al guardar el elemento");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Cuando se guarda el objeto es ahí en donde recién se procesa el archivo, mi problema es que estoy manejando las llamadas Ajax con blockUI para que e bloquee la pantalla, pero cuando guardo el archivo deja de bloquear. ¿Como podria solucionarlo?

Comment: Tendrías que publicar un código que reproduzca el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Añade a tu llamada a ajax la propiedad `async : false`

Esto provoca que la UI, o el codigo, quede bloqueada hasta que el script que corre en el servidor acabe de ejecutarse y/o devuelva un valor (si ha ido bien, mal, etc).

`Async: true` -> corre el codigo en paralelo con el servidor.

`Async: false` -> espera a que el codigo del servidor acabe de ejecutarse para continuar ejecutando la siguiente parte del codigo.

Espero haber ayudado.

Comment: Por favor agrega un poco más de detalles, tal vez explicando como tu respuesta soluciona el problema.

Comment: Listo, espero que haya ayudado.